# Importing mobile numbers into mobile connect

Tags: contact, mobileconnect, contactbuilder, import, mobilestudio

There are three different starting points on how a subscriber can opt-in through a mobile opt-in message.

1. They are a lead and are added as a separate contact in Mobile Connect when they text the opt-in keyword.
2. They are a customer that has already received text messages from us. When they text opt-in the subscription will be added to their existing contact.
3. They are a customer that we know the mobile number of but we've never send a text message to them so they are not in mobile connect yet. They decide to text opt-in and it creates a new contact for them -> not what I want.

So to avoid the behavior of option 3, I want to add all the mobile numbers of the contacts in Service Cloud to their contact in Marketing Cloud. This way they will be added to mobile connect. Take in mind that these people didn't give mobile opt-in.

When trying to create an import activity I need to specify a keyword? But this will automatically result in them being opted-in, which I don't want. I just want to have their mobile number on their contact.

How can I achieve this?